# embedding sound with beamer overlays

Tags: beamer, overlays, media9

I want to embed audio with beamer slides.  I am using media9.  I want my audio to start when a slide becomes visible, and stop when it disappears.  Without overlays this is not a problem.  But I can't make it work with overlays.  Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[noplaybutton]{media9}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Silent slide 1.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\onslide<1>{
\includemedia[
  activate=pagevisible, deactivate=pageinvisible,
  addresource=sample.mp3,
  flashvars={
    source=sample.mp3
    &autoPlay=true
  }
]{\fbox{Play}}{APlayer.swf}
Slide 2}

\onslide<2>{Slide 3}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Silent slide 4
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

A play window opens and the sound begins when slide 2 becomes visible. There is no play window on slide 3 but the sound nonetheless restarts.  And restarts again upon going back to the preceding slide 2.  The sound stops when slide 4 appears, and restarts again on returning to 3.  I want sound only on slide 2.  Not on slide 3.  Does anyone know how to do this?  Is this even possible?

Comment: Try `\only<...>{...}` instead of `\onslide<...>{...}`, at least for the `\includemedia` content.

Comment: Yes, \only works, and so I presume \uncover does as well (but have not checked).  Thanks!